# Why glyphical icons not initialized with load page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, fonts

I'm hooked bootstrap-datetimepicker and when I click on the INPUT, I do not see glyphicon icons. The font is loaded after a while.
How to load fonts when the page loads?

bootstrap-datetimepicker: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Fonts are connected via the config symfony2:

```
    bootstrap_fonts_woff:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'
        output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    bootstrap_fonts_woff2:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2'
        output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
    bootstrap_fonts_ttf:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
        output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    bootstrap_fonts_svg:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg'
        output: fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please check if you are loading  css first in the page if its coming from css. If its JS then you can probably create css classes to assign glyphicon

Comment: @SarangDamkondwar
Thanks for your feedback.

I add this fonts in global fonts.css and this not help for my. 
Developer Tool in Google chrome indicates that the font is loaded by pressing the INPUT.